# Update Action Trouble

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

this is my Update Action :

```
        public void etat(string id)
    {

            Models.J2VEntities entity = new Models.J2VEntities();

            Models.user model = (from p in entity.user
                                 where p.iduser == id
                                 select p).SingleOrDefault();

            model.IsActive = !(model.IsActive);
            entity.user.AddObject(model);
            entity.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(model, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
            entity.SaveChanges();
            RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }
```

When i excutet i got this error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: An object with the same key already exists in ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in state Modified. An object can be added back to ObjectStateManager if it is added in the state.

at this line :`entity.user.AddObject(model);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sloved with in this way :

```
using (var entity = new Models.J2VEntities())
            {
                Models.user model = (from p in entity.user
                                     where p.iduser == id
                                     select p).SingleOrDefault();
                model.IsActive = !(model.IsActive);
                entity.user.ApplyCurrentValues(model);
                entity.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
public void etat(string id){
 using( var entity = new Models.J2VEntities()){
    Models.user model = (from p in entity.user
                             where p.iduser == id
                             select p).SingleOrDefault();
    model.IsActive = !(model.IsActive);
    entity.user.Attach(model);
    entity.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
    entity.SaveChanges();
 }
}
```

The `using` will ensure that your connection is disposed and closed properly to make sure you do not have memory leaks or unwanted open connections.

Comment: this line `entity.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;` dosen't work for me underlined with red.

Comment: @Chlebta - Which part of that line is underlined? Try right clicking on the red, then selecting the option "Resolve ->" and then I am guessing you may have to include a namespace - most likely `using System.Data;`.

Comment: Yeah i made that but Entry is alway underlined, and when i go on it he tald me to generate a stub for it

Comment: @Chlebta - this must be because you are using a different API (namely ObjectContext API). Replace the line with Entry to be `entity.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(model, EntityState.Modified);`

Comment: i got this error `Can not attach the object, because it is already in the object context. An object can be attached again that when in an unmodified state.` at this line `entity.user.Attach(model);`